# Extjs 4.2 chart lined series multiple data for yfield

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

In the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.chart.series.Line) of this kind of series in the "yfield definition" says:

> The name(s) of the data Model field(s) corresponding to the y-axis value(s).

Following this, I´m trying to add two data model fields to the same yfield of a line serie.

This is a normal example: [example1](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/28aq)

But in [this example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/28dl) if I try to put two data model fields in the same yfield of the serie, the line disapears,but in the legend I see the two data names.

Is there something wrong in the code,or am I missing something?

**EDIT 1**

Maybe I have explained myself wrong, the solution Gilsha proposes is the same as the code of [example1](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/28aq).

I want something like this:

[image]

sin and cos data in the same serie, not an individual serie for each value.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add multiple field labels to the axis and multiple line series to plot each line as shown below.

```
series: [{
        type: 'line', //Plots sin
        axis: 'left',
        xField: 'theta',
        yField: 'sin',
        smooth: true,
        style: {
            'stroke-width': 4
        },
        markerConfig: {
            radius: 4
        },
        highlight: {
            shadow: false,
            fill: '#000',
            radius: 5,
            'stroke-width': 2,
            stroke: '#fff'
        }
    }, {
        type: 'line', //Plots cos
        axis: 'left',
        xField: 'theta',
        yField: 'cos',
        smooth: true,
        style: {
            'stroke-width': 4
        },
        markerConfig: {
            radius: 4
        },
        highlight: {
            shadow: false,
            fill: '#000',
            radius: 5,
            'stroke-width': 2,
            stroke: '#fff'
        }
    },{
        type: 'line', //Plots sin
        axis: 'left',
        xField: 'theta',
        yField: 'tan',
        smooth: true,
        style: {
            'stroke-width': 4
        },
        markerConfig: {
            radius: 4
        },
        highlight: {
            shadow: false,
            fill: '#000',
            radius: 5,
            'stroke-width': 2,
            stroke: '#fff'
        }
    }]
```